# Ruby EventMachine serial connection to arduino?

Tags: ruby, concurrency, arduino, eventmachine

I have a Ruby application that connects to a serial device via USB(an Arduino, non-firmata kind).

I am exploring the possiblity of using EventMachine for non-blocking bidirectional I/O but can not find any examples. **Does EvenMachine support serial connections?** We're currently using our own nonblocking IO framework and I would prefer to not reinvent the wheel.

Currently, all control is done through a Serial object via the serialport gem. I believe it is a subclass of the IO Class in Ruby.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
require 'eventmachine'

class Sender < EventMachine::Connection
  def receive_data(data)
    puts "Just got: #{data}"
  end

  def unbind
    puts "Disconnected! Did you unplug the device?"
    EM.stop
  end
end

EM.run do
  serial = SerialPort.new '/dev/ttyACM0'
  # We can do polling here to give the thread a chance to send outbound msgs.
  EventMachine::PeriodicTimer.new(2) { serial.puts "Hello!"  }
  EM.attach serial, Sender
end
```